# Interacting with contract in myetherwallet

Tags: myetherwallet, abi, internal-transactions

I have developed some smart contracts and deployed/interacted with them successfully using truffle framework. However, when copying the main smart contract's address and it's ABI into myetherwallet to interact with its functions, not all functions appear although they seem to be defined correctly in the ABI. I noticed the functions that do not appear in myetherwallet, are those that call other `internal` functions.

For example assume we have

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DemoERC20 is X, Y, Z{

...

function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
    return _balances[account];
}

function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
}

function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
    require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}

}
```

Both `balanceOf` and `transfer` are defined in the ABI, but I can only see `balanceOf` when trying to interact with the `Demo` contract over Myetherwallet. This is also the same with any function defined within contracts `X`, `Y`, or `Z`.

Comment: What network have you deployed it to, and what is its address on that network?

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be possible to call `_foo2` from `foo2`, since the latter is read-only (`view`) and the former is not. Did you actually compile this contract?

Comment: That was a mistake when writing the question. It should be virtual instead of views. Yes, I actually compiled it. I deployed it over Ropsten.

Comment: I have updated the question with some of the real functions. I was just trying to simplify it.

Comment: `balanceOf` is read-only, and `transfer`. I would imagine the MyEtherWallet shows the former in one page and the latter in another (similarly to Etherscan). Or perhaps you haven't entered your credentials, so you obviously cannot send a transaction, hence `transfer` is not showing. You have yet to answer my original question BTW.